# Unresolved external when using registerForLocalNotifications

Tags: swift, notifications, identifier

I am trying to set notification for my swift app and when I type this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    //Tell the app to ask the user for permission
    registerForLocalNotifications()
    return true

}
```

It returns `Use of unresolved identifier 'registerForLocalNotifications'`.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You're calling a function that belongs to the `ExternalAccessory` framework as if it were a function of your own class.

I think you need...

```
import ExternalAccessory
```

...among your imports and then later...

```
EAAccessoryManager.sharedAccessoryManager().registerForLocalNotifications()
```